# query dates and return value of matching field values

Tags: mysql

I need to do a query from a front-end app i'm developing that can take a date range such as "01/28/2016-01/30/2016" and search 7 date fields pd1 thru pd7 for a date within the range and then to get the value of the fields pa1 thru pa7.  so that is query for pay date within range and return the pay amount for the date field that matched.  so if i do SELECT pd1,pa1,pd2,pa2,.... FROM PAYMENTS WHERE pd1 or pd2... is ='daterange' <-- and this is where i get lost is there an easier way to do what i'm trying to do.  i'm going to get all the payments that are for the date range and sum them for a total calc of expected payments.

Comment: please give a better explanation where is your problem exactly? what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

The specification is a bit ambiguous. Assuming `pd1`,`pd2`..., `pd7` are columns of datatype `DATE`, and assuming columns `pa1`,`pa2`, ... `pa7` are numeric datatype. I'm also going to assume that your "front end application" supports prepared statements with bind placeholders. (Given the scarce information in the question, this may be too much to assume.)

Let's work with a simplified example. Given this as the data in the table:

```
pd1        pa1    pd2          pa2
---------- ----   ----------  ----
2016-01-29  100   2015-12-12    49
2015-11-11   24   2016-01-30    10
```

What result exactly are you expecting to be returned with predicates for a "date range" of `01/28/2016-01/30/2016`?

```
total
-----
  110
```

or

```
total
-----
  183
```

The specification is a bit ambiguous. I'm going to assume that you want the former result, just the total of the values of `paN` columns that correspond to a `pdN` value in the specified date rante.

There's a couple of approaches.

If you're just asking how to identify which rows to return, just split that "date range" into two fields, and re-format each of those to be in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. (I'm also going to assume that the value of the first "date" is before or equal to the the second "date".)

If you are just wanting to return the rows with a `pdN` value between the two dates:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.pd1 BETWEEN ? AND ?
    OR t.pd2 BETWEEN ? AND ?
    OR t.pd3 BETWEEN ? AND ?
    OR t.pd4 BETWEEN ? AND ?
    OR t.pd6 BETWEEN ? AND ?
    OR t.pd7 BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

If you are looking for a "total", this would be much simpler if there weren't seven columns to check. If the data were normalized, each paN and corresponding pdN on a separate row. But dealing with the unfortunate structure of the existing data, we could something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(q.tot) AS `total`
  FROM ( 
         SELECT SUM(t1.pa1) AS tot FROM mytable t1 WHERE t1.pd1 BETWEEN ? AND ?
          UNION ALL
         SELECT SUM(t2.pa2) AS tot FROM mytable t2 WHERE t2.pd2 BETWEEN ? AND ?
          UNION ALL
         SELECT SUM(t3.pa3) AS tot FROM mytable t3 WHERE t3.pd3 BETWEEN ? AND ?
          UNION ALL
         SELECT SUM(t4.pa4) AS tot FROM mytable t4 WHERE t4.pd4 BETWEEN ? AND ?
          UNION ALL
         SELECT SUM(t5.pa5) AS tot FROM mytable t5 WHERE t5.pd5 BETWEEN ? AND ?
          UNION ALL
         SELECT SUM(t6.pa6) AS tot FROM mytable t6 WHERE t6.pd6 BETWEEN ? AND ?
          UNION ALL
         SELECT SUM(t7.pa7) AS tot FROM mytable t7 WHERE t7.pd7 BETWEEN ? AND ?
       ) q
```

The earlier date value is supplied for the `?` placeholder following the `BETWEEN` keyword in each query. And the later date is supplied for the `?` placeholder following the `AND` keyword.

Again, those values will need to be supplied to the query in the MySQL standard DATE format: `YYYY-MM-DD`.  e.g. `2016-01-28` and `2016-01-30`.

For best performance of this query, you are going to want indexes defined

```
... ON mytable (pd1, pa1)
... ON mytable (pd2, pa2)
... ON mytable (pd3, pa3)
... ON mytable (pd4, pa4)
... ON mytable (pd5, pa5)
... ON mytable (pd6, pa6)
... ON mytable (pd7, pa7)
```

---

If there are no suitable indexes defined, then a single pass through the table will likely be faster.

```
SELECT SUM( IF(t.pd1 BETWEEN ? AND ?, t.pa1, 0)
          + IF(t.pd2 BETWEEN ? AND ?, t.pa2, 0)
          + IF(t.pd3 BETWEEN ? AND ?, t.pa3, 0)
          + IF(t.pd4 BETWEEN ? AND ?, t.pa4, 0)
          + IF(t.pd5 BETWEEN ? AND ?, t.pa5, 0)
          + IF(t.pd6 BETWEEN ? AND ?, t.pa6, 0)
          + IF(t.pd7 BETWEEN ? AND ?, t.pa7, 0)
       ) AS `total`
  FROM mytable t
```